# Adding/Removing events based on context

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I am new to C# and WinForms. I have some objects with the right click (context menu) events. However, depending on the context (for example depending on whether the user is in the wizard screen or the main screen), I want to alter what the right click does. I googled a bit and found that I can use `+=` and `-=` operators but I still could not achieve what I want to do. Given the code below, for example,

Any ideas ?

EDIT: I want the `OnClickCard` behave differently in different places.

Sammple Code:

```
public override ContextMenuStrip GetContextMenuStrip(GoView view)
{
    if (Selectable)
    {

        ContextMenuStrip contextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();

        if (!Empty)
        {
            // this is just for example so not showing the implementation
            contextMenu.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem(
                "Delete", 
                null, 
                new EventHandler(OnClickDelete))); 
        }

        // Empty
        else
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem addCard = new ToolStripMenuItem("Add");

                foreach (..some data..)
                {
                    ToolStripMenuItem card = new ToolStripMenuItem(
                            data,
                            null,
                            new EventHandler(OnClickCard));

                    addCard.DropDownItems.Add(card);

                }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}


private void OnClickCard(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem cardItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
    if (cardItem.Text.Contains("ABC"))
    {
        Common.Forms.FormMMUSettings f = new FormMMUSettings(cardItem.Text,ParentMagazine.NextSite);
        f.Show();
    }
    SetCard(new MagazineCard(2, cardItem.Text));
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code and we might be able to help? It either that or get directed to msdn

Comment: @show some code stuff that you have tried ........

Comment: Show your full code..

Comment: can you provide some code? I cannot see the problem as you can display contextmenu1 in mainform and contexmenu2 in the wizard.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you want to change the contents of the context menu depending on the circumstances when it's clicked? If so, the easiest way is to create multiple context menus, and just use an event to set whichever context menu you want.

```
ContextMenu menu1 = new ContextMenu();

MenuItem menu1Item1 = new MenuItem();
menu1Item1.Header = "Menu 1 Item 1";
menu1Item1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(menu1Item1Clicked);
menu1.Items.Add(mnu1Item1);

MenuItem menu1Item2 = new MenuItem();
menu1Item2.Header = "Menu 1 Item 2";
menu1Item2.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(menu1Item2Clicked);
menu1.Items.Add(menu1Item2);

ContextMenu menu2 = new ContextMenu();

MenuItem menu2Item1 = new MenuItem();
menu2Item1.Header = "Menu 2 Item 1";
menu2Item1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(menu2Item1Clicked);
menu2.Items.Add(menu2Item1);

MenuItem menu2Item2 = new MenuItem();
menu2Item2.Header = "Menu 2 Item 2";
menu2Item2.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(menu2Item2Clicked);
menu2.Items.Add(menu2Item2);

public void menu1Item1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

etc..
```

Now you can just set whichever menu you need using:

```
myForm.ContextMenu = menu1;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`+=` and `-=` should work just fine but I'd suggest you to use a kind of handlers repo where you'd switch which handler to use. This should work like a [strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern where different wizard steps would be different strategies.

*It would be easier to help you if you'll show us some code and point us which code parts do not work properly.*

Answer (score 0):

You seem to suggest that you would like to attach different handlers depending on context:

```
if(that)
    obj.event += HandleThat;
else
    obj.event += HandleSomethingElse;
```

That should work, but you can also do it in one handler:

```
obj.event += HandleAll;

void HandleAll(object sender, EventArgs arg) {
    if(that)
        HandleThat();
    else
        HandleSomethingElse();
}
```

EDIT: ok, your edited question really meant something else.

First obvious problem is that you add `OnClickDelete` as a handler, and show the implementation of `OnClickCard` which will not be called in your example. If it is a typo, then you just need to implement the handler method as you need. What part exactly is not working?

Comment: `OnClickDelete`  method is just for example so I did not show its implementation (though a definition exists in the real code)